# Auto Timsetamp formula is extending but not calculating correct/Today's date

Tags: microsoft-excel, timestamp

`=IF([@Code1]<>"",IF([@[Auto DT]]<>"",[@[Auto DT]],NOW()),"")`

This formula to get timestamp in column [Auto DT].
Currently

Step1 = I add code in new row. New row is added in the table. Auto date becomes 0-jan.

Step 2= I remove the new code. Date also disappears. Newly added row remains empty.

Step 3= I write the code again and I get today's date.

I want only step 1. it should show correct date.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a circular reference and not `=IF([@Code1]<>"",NOW(),"")`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad using circular reference, is a way to "freeze" the date to the first time the cell goes from blank to filled.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info

Comment: So, just reading the comments: The "freeze" happens immediately, i.e. "before your expected time", when the date-value still is "0". <- might this be an eye opener?